# Why are my floats not working properly?

Tags: html, css, layout

The floats will clear and the articles just stack up and float left. I tried clearing both on the image and the articles but to no avail.

Code:

```css
#Bottom_row {
    clear: both;
    height: 600px;
}
#Bottom_Column > img {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}
.Article_Sec {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<section id="Bottom_row">
    <img src="Images/pic_sure.png">
    <article class="Article_Sec">
        <div class="Content_area">
            <h3 class="category">Apps</h3>
            <p class="latest">5 Tips to make your laptop run like the day you bought it!</p>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="Article_Sec">
        <div class="Content_area">
            <h3 class="category">Apps</h3>
            <p class="latest">5 Tips to make your laptop run like the day you bought it!</p>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="Article_Sec">
        <div class="Content_area">
            <h3 class="category">Apps</h3>
            <p class="latest">5 Tips to make your laptop run like the day you bought it!</p>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="Article_Sec">
        <div class="Content_area">
            <h3 class="category">Apps</h3>
            <p class="latest">5 Tips to make your laptop run like the day you bought it!</p>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't write clear in the floated div. Write to parent div.

```css
#Bottom_row{
  clear:both;
  height:600px;
  
}

#Bottom_row > img{
  float:left;
}
       
.Article_Sec{
   float:left;
   width:25%;
}
```

```html
<section id="Bottom_row">
                <img src="Images/pic_sure.png">
                <article class="Article_Sec">
        <div class="Content_area">
                    <h3 class="category">Apps</h3>
                    <p class="latest">5 Tips to make your laptop run like the day you bought it!</p>
                    </div>
       </article>
                <article class="Article_Sec">
        <div class="Content_area">
                    <h3 class="category">Apps</h3>
                    <p class="latest">5 Tips to make your laptop run like the day you bought it!</p>
                    </div>
       </article>
                <article class="Article_Sec">
        <div class="Content_area">
                    <h3 class="category">Apps</h3>
                    <p class="latest">5 Tips to make your laptop run like the day you bought it!</p>
                    </div>
       </article>
                <article class="Article_Sec">
        <div class="Content_area">
                    <h3 class="category">Apps</h3>
                    <p class="latest">5 Tips to make your laptop run like the day you bought it!</p>
                    </div>
       </article>
            </section>
```

**Edit:**

I misunderstood question. Then make either  image `width` 100% Or put image in another div and give `width:100%` to that div.

```css
#Bottom_row{
  clear:both;
  height:600px;
}

#Bottom_row > img{
  float:left;
}

.imgDiv{
  width:100%
  }
       
.Article_Sec{
   float:left;
   width:25%;
}
```

```html
<section id="Bottom_row">
                <div class="imgDiv">
                <img src="Images/pic_sure.png">
                  </div>
                <article class="Article_Sec">
        <div class="Content_area">
                    <h3 class="category">Apps</h3>
                    <p class="latest">5 Tips to make your laptop run like the day you bought it!</p>
                    </div>
       </article>
                <article class="Article_Sec">
        <div class="Content_area">
                    <h3 class="category">Apps</h3>
                    <p class="latest">5 Tips to make your laptop run like the day you bought it!</p>
                    </div>
       </article>
                <article class="Article_Sec">
        <div class="Content_area">
                    <h3 class="category">Apps</h3>
                    <p class="latest">5 Tips to make your laptop run like the day you bought it!</p>
                    </div>
       </article>
                <article class="Article_Sec">
        <div class="Content_area">
                    <h3 class="category">Apps</h3>
                    <p class="latest">5 Tips to make your laptop run like the day you bought it!</p>
                    </div>
       </article>
            </section>
```

Comment: Thanks this actually works except for the articles being pushed right next to the image and not breaking under the image

Comment: It still doesn't work all of the articles end up inline with the image.I want the articles under the image

Comment: @Chris, could you check it now?

Comment: @Chris Sorry i misunderstood your question. Check my edited answer.

Comment: @ketan thank you very much for the help it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `clear` in the CSS for `.Article_Sec` was causing the issue.Check the snippet
Code:

```css
     #Bottom_row{
            clear:both;
            height:600px;
                
        }
        #Bottom_Column > img{
          clear:both;
            float:left;
         }
        .Article_Sec{
            float:left;
         
            width:25%;
            
        }
```

```html
   <section id="Bottom_row">
                <img src="Images/pic_sure.png">
                <article class="Article_Sec">
        <div class="Content_area">
                    <h3 class="category">Apps</h3>
                    <p class="latest">5 Tips to make your laptop run like the day you bought it!</p>
                    </div>
       </article>
                <article class="Article_Sec">
        <div class="Content_area">
                    <h3 class="category">Apps</h3>
                    <p class="latest">5 Tips to make your laptop run like the day you bought it!</p>
                    </div>
       </article>
                <article class="Article_Sec">
        <div class="Content_area">
                    <h3 class="category">Apps</h3>
                    <p class="latest">5 Tips to make your laptop run like the day you bought it!</p>
                    </div>
       </article>
                <article class="Article_Sec">
        <div class="Content_area">
                    <h3 class="category">Apps</h3>
                    <p class="latest">5 Tips to make your laptop run like the day you bought it!</p>
                    </div>
       </article>
            </section>
```

Comment: Thanks it actually is inline now but the articles are being pushed up next to the image

Answer (score 0):

if you want to clear image floating just add 
 after image .
if you want to float the articles delete clear both from .Article_Sec

```css
#Bottom_row{
        clear:both;
        height:600px;

    }
    #Bottom_Column > img{
      clear:both;
        float:left;
     }
    .Article_Sec{
        float:left;
        clear:both;
        width:25%;

    }
```

```html
<section id="Bottom_row">
            <img src="Images/pic_sure.png"><br />
            <article class="Article_Sec">
                <div class="Content_area">
                <h3 class="category">Apps</h3>
                <p class="latest">5 Tips to make your laptop run like the day you bought it!</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="Article_Sec">
                <div class="Content_area">
                <h3 class="category">Apps</h3>
                <p class="latest">5 Tips to make your laptop run like the day you bought it!</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="Article_Sec">
                <div class="Content_area">
                <h3 class="category">Apps</h3>
                <p class="latest">5 Tips to make your laptop run like the day you bought it!</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="Article_Sec">
                <div class="Content_area">
                <h3 class="category">Apps</h3>
                <p class="latest">5 Tips to make your laptop run like the day you bought it!</p>
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
```

Comment: Thanks but the articles display one after the other with this change i want them inline

Comment: if you want to float the articles delete clear both from .Article_Sec .
only delete clear both from .Article_Sec
.Article_Sec{
        float:left;
        width:25%;

    }